# fio: how to reduce verbosity?

Tags: benchmark, fio

When I run fio command, I get huge file with following lines which fills up the entire space. I am interested in only the final fio output summary. How can I reduce this fio verbosity?

```
::::
Jobs: 4 (f=4): [W(3),X(1),R(1)][0.1%][r=1244MiB/s,w=2232MiB/s][r=319k,w=17.9k IOPS][eta 03h:04m:45s]
Jobs: 4 (f=4): [W(3),X(1),R(1)][0.1%][r=1243MiB/s,w=2252MiB/s][r=318k,w=18.0k IOPS][eta 03h:02m:18s]
::::
```

fio is run using following command.

```
[root@system user]# fio  iops_wipc.fio --eta=always --eta-newline=1 | tee /tmp/iops_wipc_op

[root@system user]# cat iops_wipc.fio
[wipc-iops]
group_reporting
direct=1
ioengine=libaio
allow_mounted_write=1
refill_buffers
scramble_buffers=1
thread=1
#eta-newline=10
bs=128k
numjobs=4
iodepth=32
rw=write
size=768G
[device0]
filename=/dev/nvme2n1
```

Comment: Did you try it with option `--terse-version=3` ?

Comment: Thanks. Does removing $eta_always$ and $eta-newline$ can help here?

Comment: Sure, just try it. In fact you did since you had it as `eta-newline=10` in your jobfile. What you can do simultaneously is do away with `eta=always` and only play with `eta-newline`. But is the question about only having the last job's last line(s) ?  Can you detail that somewhat ?

Answer (score 0):

- If you aren't interested in the ETA you can [turn it off with --eta=never](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-eta) as mentioned in the documentation.
- If you are only interested in the final ETA (?) won't the summary have the information you're after?
- If you're machine processing the summary you would be better off using the one of the machine readable formats https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-output-format ?
- If you were interested in bandwidth over time have you seen [`write_bw_log`](https://fio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fio_doc.html#cmdoption-arg-write-bw-log) ?